# Confused! What are the differences between code first and code only?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm kind of confusing about these two term. Could someone have a bit explain these terms?

I know the one is like, that we define our POCO classes, and then create a class that has a set of DbSet which inherited from DbContext.

Comment: It's the same thing - that approach was called "code-only" at first, and later on, Microsoft started talking about "code-first" (since they already have database-first and model-first). But as far as I understand it, those two terms mean the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Code-only development](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/22/feature-ctp-walkthrough-code-only-for-the-entity-framework.aspx) and [code-first development](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) are the same thing, both are utilizing Entity Framework without a physical EDMX file, everything is handled in code.